# PDO access.mdb not excape percent during SELECT query in a prepared statement

Tags: php, pdo

I don't know if it's a problem only for PDO connecting to a MDB ACCESS database (and not to MySQL), but i've problem in all SELECT query where I insert a `%` using prepared statement.

This is my example:

```
Table.Col1 is a TEXT field
Table.Col2 is a INT field
```

When I search inside `Col1` I want to search exact term (not starting with...or end with...but the exact term I pass)

Example of a compiled Table

```
| ID | Col1      | Col2 |
-------------------------
| 1  | test      | 23   |
-------------------------
| 2  | apple     | 24   |
-------------------------
| 3  | applejuice| 33   |
-------------------------
| 4  | yellow    | 76   |
-------------------------
| 5  | brown     | 50   |
-------------------------



<?php

$dbName = "Database.mdb";

try{
    $db= new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    exit();
}

function test($filters = array()) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE 1";
    $vars = array();

    //  FILTER BY Col1

    if ( isset($filters['Col1']) && $filters['Col1'] != "" ) {

        $sql .= " AND [Table].[Col1] LIKE ?";
        $vars[] = $filters['Col1'];

    }

    //  FILTER BY Col2

    if ( isset($filters['Col2']) && $filters['Col2'] != "" ) {

        $sql .= " AND [Table].[Col2] = ?";
        $vars[] = $filters['Col2'];

    }


        try {
            $s = $db->prepare($sql);
            $s->execute($vars);
            $ris = $s->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $ris;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e);
        }

}
```

Now this is my tests:

```
var_dump(test(array("Col1" => "test")));

// OUTPUT CORRECT

array(
  0 => array(
    "ID" => 1,
    "Col1" => test,
    "Col2" => 23
  )
);

var_dump(test(array("Col1" => "apple")));

// OUTPUT CORRECT

array(
  0 => array(
    "ID" => 2,
    "Col1" => applejuice,
    "Col2" => 33
  )
);

 var_dump(test(array("Col1" => "%")));

// OUTPUT INCORRECT !!!!
// I GET ALL TABLE!!! I WANT TO RETRIEVE A EMPTY RESULT ARRAY

array(
  0 => array(
    "ID" => 1,
    "Col1" => test,
    "Col2" => 23
  ),
  1 => array(
    "ID" => 2,
    "Col1" => apple,
    "Col2" => 24
  ),
  2 => array(
    "ID" => 3,
    "Col1" => applejuice,
    "Col2" => 33
  ),
  3 => array(
    "ID" => 4,
    "Col1" => yellow,
    "Col2" => 76
  ),
  4 => array(
    "ID" => 5,
    "Col1" => brown,
    "Col2" => 50
  ),
  0 => array(
    "ID" => 2,
    "Col1" => applejuice,
    "Col2" => 33
  )
);
```

Why prepared statement doesn't work? I've a lot of function where I need to SELECT where I search for a EXACT TEST... How can I solve this problem with `%` for ALL my tables without rewrite all my function (more than 100 function in my project!!!)?

Comment: % is a wildcard operator also in Access AFAIK. So this is the right behaviour for your syntax. You are asking to return all the records that in col1 as any char. You should escape it

Comment: prepared statement doesn't excape it yourself? What's the best way to excape it (in a PDO using access db connection) and modify all my functions (a lot) without pain? Thanks

Comment: PDO cannot understand the difference between % as a char or % as a wildcard. You need to escape it with backticks to say to mysql to consider it as a char

Comment: Basically, where I've a LIKE, i've to use always: $var = str_replace("%","\%",$var); $var = str_replace("_","\ _",$var); in all my functions?

Comment: the syntax for a like is %$var% if it contains $var, $var% if it begins with $var and %$var if it ends with $var. I don't get what you say about str_replace. Just pass the % wrapped around **backticks** and mysql will read it as a char and not as a wildcard operator

Comment: btw you have already another answer to the same question where another user was suggesting to escape the % using %%. Is this not working? Why asking again the same question?

Comment: I don't use MySQL but PDO connection to mdb access database